# File Upload Control cannot handle large files (greater than 75MB) in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, large-files

I am using a FileUpload Control in my application for uploading a text file. 
This control works fine for smaller files, but when I am trying to upload a 80MB file, Browser  displays an empty page and shows "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : Thank you Sriram, I didn't check that post before.

Answer (score 0):

In the begining I could not understand this wierd behaviour as Empty page was displayed after submitting the page even before particular even is called. 
Ex: I had to call buttonClick event, but when I click that button empty page was coming.

The solution for this is to add the httpRunTime execution timeout and maxRequestLength properties.

Add the following to  section of your web.config file.

```
<system.web>
       -- some code -- 
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="102400" />
       --some code --
</system.web>
```

I hope this will help you.